# nested Group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in a Oracle database:

```
Name    Place     Color
------- --------- --------
John    Paris     Blue
John    Miami     Blue
Ryan    Boston    Red
Ryan    Boston    Red
Jim     Miami     Blue
Ryan    Oslo      Red
Jason   Rome      Green
Jim     Paris     Blue
Jason   Rome      Green
Jim     Paris     Blue
Ryan    Boston    Red
```

I need to dedup if two columns are the same(name/place) and then count by a third column. I am trying to group by twice with a nested select but I keep getting an ORA-00933 error.

```
select Color, count(Color)
from
(
    select TO_CHAR(Name)||'-'||(Place) as unique_ident from mytable
    group by TO_CHAR(Name)||'-'||(Place)
) as inline
group by Color
```

I would to return something like

```
Blue   4
Red    2
Green  1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT Color, COUNT(DISTINCT name || '-' || place) ColorCnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Color
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/334d6/1)

Resulting In:

```
COLOR   ColorCnt
-----------------
Green   1
Blue    4
Red     2
```

Comment: @Lance -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this give you the results you want?

```
select TO_CHAR(Name)||'-'||(Place) , color, count(*) as color_count
from mytable
group by name, place, color
```

Comment: COUNT(*) won't work in this case -- it would return 5 for Blue for example.

Comment: Yep, I did not understand. sgeddes got it.

Comment: No, this won't work.  It will return "1" for almost all the rows because you are grouping by name, place, and color.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by sgeddes is fine.  The problem with your query is that your outer query references `color`, but it is not in your inner query.  You can fix this by doing:

```
select Color, count(Color)
from (select TO_CHAR(Name)||'-'||(Place) as unique_ident, color
      from mytable
      group by TO_CHAR(Name)||'-'||(Place), color
     ) as inline 
group by Color;
```

However, the `count(distinct)` formulation is probably preferable.